# Opacity won't animate during scroll or touchmove events on iOS device

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

We're making elements "active" and animating their opacity from 0.2 to 1 based on which element is most on screen using JQuery. However on iOS the active class can be seen to be applied during the touchmove event but the animation to show the element does not.

Is this possible view CSS or will we have to use something like iScroll to take over the scrolling of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's just how iOs works. The animation actually happens once the touch event ends, not during like in desktop. Plugins like ScrollMagic rely on iScroll for smoothing things out.